# How to compare a time for a give schedule between time from - time to

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can in check if the schedule exist between the given time interval in SQL
More Clearly to underatand

```
Select * 
From [Client].[scheduler] 
Where [Scheduler_Date] = '6/16/2012' 
    and ([start]<='13:06 ') 
    and ([end]>='14:31 ')
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your query then ?

Comment: I don't think that you can apply `>=` or `<=` operator on string values placed inside quotes like `'11:00'`

Comment: You can use <> operator with string values for example WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR,timeColumn,108) >= '01:01:01' but best way is  Between operator

Comment: What's the table definition? Any reason why `time_from` and `time_to` aren't being stored as `time`?

Comment: If your using sql server 2008 u can use time instead of converting to varchar  ex CONVERT(time(0),time_from ())>='11:00'

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest avoiding strings and using the `time` datatype:

```
select * from  [Client].[scheduler] 
where [Scheduler_Date] = '20120616' and 
      (CONVERT(time,[time_from])>='11:00') and 
      (CONVERT(time,[time_to])<='13:06')
```

(Why are `time_from` and `time_to` not already `time`s?)

I've also adjusted the date string literal to use a safe format (yyyymmdd)

---

On the other hand, it strikes me that you might be wanting to find any schedules that overlap (partially, or entirely) with the given end points. The trick there is to switch the comparisons:

```
where [Scheduler_Date] = '20120616' and 
      (CONVERT(time,[time_from])<='13:06') and 
      (CONVERT(time,[time_to])>='11:00')
```

This new `WHERE` clause will find any rows that overlap the 11:00-13:06 time period, not just those wholly contained within it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * 
from  [Client].[scheduler] 
where [Scheduler_Date] = '6/16/2012' and 
      (CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),[time_from],108) LIKE '11%') and 
      (CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),[time_to],108) LIKE '13:06%')
```